# How to run python script without using ./script.py?

Tags: python

I have a script.py that I'd like to run when the user types "script" in unix. How do I accomplish this, instead of forcing him to type ./script.py each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the directory of the script in your `PATH` environment variable.

e.g.

```
/path/to/script.py
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to
```

To obviate typing the extension create a local symlink

```
ln -s /path/to/script.py /path/to/script
```

This prevents polluting `/usr/local/bin` with manual symlinks (which could be important on a multi-user) system.

Comment: That doesn't take care of the extension.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add a symlink to the script, without using the .py extension, and place it somewhere on your system path. For instance, you might do

```
sudo ln -s myscript.py /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

Then you will need neither the `.py` nor the `./`.