# How to make your own commands

Tags: python, linux

I am new to linux.

I made a python script that takes two input

Input 1> directory path ex:- `~/home/user/apps`

Input 2> `file path`

File contains pattern in each line

And the output of script is all the file that matches the pattern  and are in directory or in subdirectories of input directory path.

Now using this python script I want to make a command in Linux like:

`core_dump@core_dump-VPCCB15FG:~/python$search directory_path file_path`

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373693/how-to-run-python-script-without-using-script-py/15373737#15373737

Answer (score 3):

In your `bashrc` file you can add the directory your script is coded in into your path then call it from anywhere:

```
export PATH=/home/user/path/to/script:$PATH
```

Or you can make an alias in your bashrc

```
alias my_find_script='python /home/user/path/to/script'
```

Then call your script in your shell:

```
$ my_find_script directory_path file_path
```

Answer (score 1):

add the program to your /bin directory - it's where linux will search for the command